# How to get value from dynamically created inputs jquery

Tags: jquery

Value from a added field return undefined.

my added input

```
 var i = 1;
$('#add_field').click(function(){
   i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td class="col-md-5"><textarea id="name" class="borders table-control" type="text" rows="1" cols="45" name="name[]"></textarea></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control price" type="text" id="price name="price[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control qty" id="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control total" id="total" type="text" name="total[]"></td><td class="text-center"><span id="'+i+'" style="color: red" name="remove" class="btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td></tr>');

});
```

this is my jquery code to get values from inputs

```
$(document).on('change', '#dynamic_field', function(event){


    var id = $('#prod_id').val();  <----I got the id.

    var name = $('#name').val();  <-----cant get value name 
    var price = $("#price").val();  <-----cant get value price 
    var qty = $("#qty").val();  <-----cant get value qty 
    var total = $("#total").val();  <-----cant get value total
```

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your ids to classes, your `#dynamic_field` isn't a input so you don't have a change event,

Lets say you change the values on the price input:

```js
var i = 1;
    $('#add_field').click(function(){
       i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td class="col-md-5"><textarea class="name borders table-control" type="text" rows="1" cols="45" name="name[]"></textarea></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control price" type="text" name="price[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control total" type="text" name="total[]"></td><td class="text-center"><span id="'+i+'" style="color: red" name="remove" class="btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td></tr>');
    
    });


    $('body').on('change','.price',function(){
        var closestParent = $(this).closest('tr');//get the values relative to the parent
        var name = closestParent.find('.name').val(); 
        var price = closestParent.find(".price").val(); 
        var qty = closestParent.find(".qty").val(); 
        var total = closestParent.find(".total").val(); 
        console.log(name,price,qty,total);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add_field">Add</button>
<div id="dynamic_field"></div>
```

Comment: Still can't get values. as there would be multiple `tr`.

Answer (score -1):

`#dynamic_field` is not input, so it does not have `change` event. Add change event handler for `input` and `textarea`.

Consider, changing `id` selector to `class` selectors, as `id` selector will return you only first matching element, so this code won't work for subsequent rows.

```js
 var i = 1;
$('#add_field').click(function(){
   i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td class="col-md-5"><textarea id="name" class="borders table-control" type="text" rows="1" cols="45" name="name[]"></textarea></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control price" type="text" id="price" name="price[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control qty" id="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control total" id="total" type="text" name="total[]"></td><td class="text-center"><span id="'+i+'" style="color: red" name="remove" class="btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td></tr>');

});

$('#dynamic_field').on('change', 'input, textarea', function(event){


    var id = $('#prod_id').val(); 

    var name = $('#name').val();  
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();  
    var total = $("#total").val(); 
    
    console.log(name, price, qty, total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dynamic_field">
</table>
<button id="add_field">
Add Fields
</button>
```

Also, avoid generating HTML in JS (as string) and consider using Templates. eg. -[Jquery Templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

Comment: Realized after posting, looks like you went through many edits. couldn't follow.